# ansible-vault: possible to *not* decrypt file

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I would like to deploy encrypted (by ansible-vault) files using ansible without providing the vault password. The files should remain encrypted and only be decrypted on the server if needed (using a separate script).

Is that possible somehow?

*Some more explanation: I am using the Ansible script to set up a CI server (bamboo, jenkins). Passwords should not live in plain text on that server, they should be decrypted on the fly when used to add another layer of security.*

Comment: Downvoting without commenting sucks. What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the latest version (2.4). There is a *decrypt* flag for the copy module, see [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/copy_module.html). This is how I use it:

**<role>/tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: Copying (encrypted) Vault Content
  copy:
    src: "templates/vault/"
    dest: "{{vault_folder}}"
    directory_mode: yes
    decrypt: no
```

On the server, I am using this line in a script to get the decrypted content of the file:

```
ansible-vault decrypt <vault_folder>/<file> --output -
```

Comment: can you share the example tasks, so that it will help other